# Processing mousePressed equivalent on mobile devices

Tags: processing

I have a Processing "app" of sorts, which allows the user to draw anything. It works well on the desktop (which has a mouse), but on my iPhone it isn't perfect yet.

Right now, when the user touches the screen to draw, a white line appears as he/she moves a finger across the screen, just as it should be. However, when the finger is lifted and placed on another part of the screen, a new line, separate from the first, is not made. Instead, the original line jumps to the spot the user touches. I want a new line to be started both on the desktop and mobile.

Here is the code:

```java
void setup() {
    size(screen.width, screen.height);
    background(0);
}

void draw() {
    stroke(225);
    strokeWeight(4);
    smooth();
    if (mousePressed) {
        line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}
```

My theory for why this is happening: on a mobile device there is no     "`mousePressed`", or any of the other commands that have the term `mouse`. So when the user attempts to start another line, the code thinks that he/she never lifted their finger to begin with.

How do I solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're not thinking about it quite correctly: the `mousePressed` variable is working exactly as intended on your mobile device- if it weren't, you would never see any lines.

The issue is with the `pmouseX` and `pmouseY` variables. Those variables hold the previous location of your mouse. On your desktop, that location is the previous location of your cursor. As you move your cursor around, the `pmouseX` and `pmouseY` variables are updated.

However, on a mobile device, you don't have a cursor, so the `pmouseX` and `pmouseY` variables hold the last location that you touched with your finger. That's what's causing the behavior you're seeing.

To get around this, you'll have to use your own variables that you set using the mouse event functions, that way you have more control over them. Something like this:

```java
boolean newTouch = true;
float previousTouchX;
float previousTouchY;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  background(0);
}

void draw() {
  stroke(225);
  strokeWeight(4);
  smooth();

  if (mousePressed) {
    if (newTouch) {
      newTouch = false;
    } else {
      line(previousTouchX, previousTouchY, mouseX, mouseY);
    }

    previousTouchX = mouseX;
    previousTouchY = mouseY;
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
  newTouch = true;
}
```